# Converting XML into data frame

Tags: r

I'm have a very difficult time converting an XML file into a data table in R.  Below is a sample of the XML data.  Would anyone have a recommendation on how to covert this to a data frame?  These XML files are coming from the following source: https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/InvestmentAdviserData.aspx  Any help one could provide would be greatly appreciated here.  Thank you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <IAPDFirmSECReport GenOn="2019-02-04">
    <Firms>
    <Firm>
    <Info SECRgnCD="BRO" FirmCrdNb="170562" SECNb="802-112318" BusNm="ALUMNI VENTURES GROUP" LegalNm="LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC"/>
    <MainAddr Strt1="788 ELM ST" City="MANCHESTER" State="NH" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="03101" PhNb="603-518-8112"/>
    <MailingAddr Strt1="889 ELM ST" Strt2="3RD FLOOR" City="MANCHESTER" State="NH" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="03101"/>
    <Rgstn FirmType="ERA" St="ACTIVE" Dt="2017-12-18"/>
    <NoticeFiled/>
    <Filing Dt="2018-07-23" FormVrsn="10/2017"/>
    <FormInfo>
    <Part1A>
    <Item1 Q1F5="5" Q1I="Y" Q1M="N" Q1N="N" Q1O="N">
    <WebAddrs>
    <WebAddr>HTTP://WWW.LAUNCH-ANGELS.COM</WebAddr>
    </WebAddrs>
    </Item1>
    <Item2A/>
    <Item2B Q2B1="Y" Q2B2="Y" Q2B3="N"/>
    <Item3A OrgFormNm="Limited Liability Company"/>
    <Item3B Q3B="DECEMBER"/>
    <Item3C StateCD="MA" CntryNm="United States"/>
    <Item5A/>
    <Item5B/>
    <Item5C/>
    <Item5D/>
    <Item5E/>
    <Item5F/>
    <Item5G/>
    <Item5H/>
    <Item5I/>
    <Item5J/>
    <Item6A/>
    <Item6B Q6B1="Y" Q6B2="Y" Q6B3="Y"/>
    <Item7A/>
    <Item7B Q7B="Y"/>
    <Item8A/>
    <Item8B/>
    <Item8C/>
    <Item8D/>
    <Item8E/>
    <Item8F/>
    <Item8G/>
    <Item8H/>
    <Item8I/>
    <Item9A/>
    <Item9B/>
    <Item9C/>
    <Item9D/>
    <Item9E/>
    <Item9F/>
    <Item10A Q10A="N"/>
    <Item11 Q11="N"/>
    <Item11A Q11A1="N" Q11A2="N"/>
    <Item11B Q11B1="N" Q11B2="N"/>
    <Item11C Q11C1="N" Q11C2="N" Q11C3="N" Q11C4="N" Q11C5="N"/>
    <Item11D Q11D1="N" Q11D2="N" Q11D3="N" Q11D4="N" Q11D5="N"/>
    <Item11E Q11E1="N" Q11E2="N" Q11E3="N" Q11E4="N"/>
    <Item11F Q11F="N"/>
    <Item11G Q11G="N"/>
    <Item11H Q11H1A="N" Q11H1B="N" Q11H1C="N" Q11H2="N"/>
    </Part1A>
    </FormInfo>
    </Firm>
    <Firm>
    <Info SECRgnCD="DRO" FirmCrdNb="116085" SECNb="801-63010" BusNm="JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT" LegalNm="JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, LLC" UmbrRgstn="N"/>
    <MainAddr Strt1="101 SOUTH 200 EAST" Strt2="SUITE 524" City="SALT LAKE CITY" State="UT" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="84111" PhNb="801.746.7171" FaxNb="385.313.8631"/>
    <MailingAddr/>
    <Rgstn FirmType="Registered" St="APPROVED" Dt="2004-04-07"/>
    <NoticeFiled>
    <States RgltrCd="AZ" St="FILED" Dt="2009-12-10"/>
    <States RgltrCd="TX" St="FILED" Dt="2017-02-14"/>
    <States RgltrCd="UT" St="FILED" Dt="2009-12-10"/>
    </NoticeFiled>
    <Filing Dt="2019-01-24" FormVrsn="10/2017"/>
    <FormInfo>
    <Part1A>
    <Item1 Q1F5="0" Q1I="Y" Q1M="N" Q1N="N" Q1O="N">
    <WebAddrs>
    <WebAddr>HTTP://WWW.JACOBSENCAPITAL.COM</WebAddr>
    </WebAddrs>
    </Item1>
    <Item2A Q2A1="Y" Q2A2="N" Q2A4="N" Q2A5="N" Q2A6="N" Q2A7="N" Q2A8="N" Q2A9="N" Q2A10="N" Q2A11="N" Q2A12="N" Q2A13="N"/>
    <Item2B/>
    <Item3A OrgFormNm="Limited Liability Company"/>
    <Item3B Q3B="NOVEMBER"/>
    <Item3C StateCD="UT" CntryNm="United States"/>
    <Item5A TtlEmp="5"/>
    <Item5B Q5B1="5" Q5B2="0" Q5B3="5" Q5B4="2" Q5B5="0" Q5B6="0"/>
    <Item5C Q5C1="0" Q5C2="0"/>
    <Item5D Q5DA1="37" Q5DA3="218242101" Q5DB1="43" Q5DB3="14664437" Q5DG1="1" Q5DG3="1325467" Q5DH1="2" Q5DH3="8078009" Q5DK1="1" Q5DK3="2932559" Q5DN1="1" Q5DN3="3143" Q5DN3Oth="FAMILY LLC"/>
    <Item5E Q5E1="Y" Q5E2="Y" Q5E3="N" Q5E4="Y" Q5E5="N" Q5E6="N" Q5E7="N"/>
    <Item5F Q5F1="Y" Q5F2A="245245716" Q5F2B="0" Q5F2C="245245716" Q5F2D="432" Q5F2E="0" Q5F2F="432" Q5F3="0"/>
    <Item5G Q5G1="N" Q5G2="Y" Q5G3="N" Q5G4="N" Q5G5="N" Q5G6="Y" Q5G7="Y" Q5G8="N" Q5G9="N" Q5G10="N" Q5G11="N" Q5G12="N"/>
    <Item5H Q5H="26-50"/>
    <Item5I Q5I1="N"/>
    <Item5J Q5J1="N" Q5J2="N"/>
    <Item6A/>
    <Item6B Q6B1="N" Q6B3="N"/>
    <Item7A Q7A1="N" Q7A2="Y" Q7A3="N" Q7A4="N" Q7A5="N" Q7A6="N" Q7A7="N" Q7A8="N" Q7A9="N" Q7A10="N" Q7A11="N" Q7A12="N" Q7A13="N" Q7A14="N" Q7A15="N" Q7A16="N"/>
    <Item7B Q7B="N"/>
    <Item8A Q8A1="N" Q8A2="Y" Q8A3="N"/>
    <Item8B Q8B1="N" Q8B2="N" Q8B3="N"/>
    <Item8C Q8C1="Y" Q8C2="Y" Q8C3="N" Q8C4="N"/>
    <Item8D/>
    <Item8E Q8E="N"/>
    <Item8F/>
    <Item8G Q8G1="N"/>
    <Item8H Q8H1="N" Q8H2="Y"/>
    <Item8I Q8I="N"/>
    <Item9A Q9A1A="N" Q9A1B="N"/>
    <Item9B Q9B1A="N" Q9B1B="N"/>
    <Item9C Q9C1="N" Q9C2="N" Q9C3="N" Q9C4="N"/>
    <Item9D Q9D1="N" Q9D2="N"/>
    <Item9E/>
    <Item9F Q9F="1"/>
    <Item10A Q10A="N"/>
    <Item11 Q11="N"/>
    <Item11A Q11A1="N" Q11A2="N"/>
    <Item11B Q11B1="N" Q11B2="N"/>
    <Item11C Q11C1="N" Q11C2="N" Q11C3="N" Q11C4="N" Q11C5="N"/>
    <Item11D Q11D1="N" Q11D2="N" Q11D3="N" Q11D4="N" Q11D5="N"/>
    <Item11E Q11E1="N" Q11E2="N" Q11E3="N" Q11E4="N"/>
    <Item11F Q11F="N"/>
    <Item11G Q11G="N"/>
    <Item11H Q11H1A="N" Q11H1B="N" Q11H1C="N" Q11H2="N"/>
    </Part1A>
    </FormInfo>
    </Firm>
    <Firm>
    <Info SECRgnCD="CHRO" FirmCrdNb="129963" SECNb="801-62669" BusNm="MINNEAPOLIS PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT GROUP, LLC" LegalNm="MINNEAPOLIS PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT GROUP, LLC" UmbrRgstn="N"/>
    <MainAddr Strt1="80 SOUTH 8TH STREET" Strt2="SUITE 2825" City="MINNEAPOLIS" State="MN" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="55402" PhNb="(612) 334-2000" FaxNb="(612) 334-2001"/>
    <MailingAddr/>
    <Rgstn FirmType="Registered" St="APPROVED" Dt="2004-01-14"/>
    <NoticeFiled>
    <States RgltrCd="AL" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="AZ" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="CA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="FL" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-29"/>
    <States RgltrCd="GA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="IL" St="FILED" Dt="2004-04-07"/>
    <States RgltrCd="IA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-04-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="LA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MI" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MO" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NE" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="CO" St="FILED" Dt="2006-07-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MS" St="FILED" Dt="2006-07-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="CT" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="ID" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="IN" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MD" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="HI" St="FILED" Dt="2011-02-25"/>
    <States RgltrCd="KS" St="FILED" Dt="2011-02-25"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MT" St="FILED" Dt="2011-02-25"/>
    <States RgltrCd="ME" St="FILED" Dt="2009-11-09"/>
    <States RgltrCd="MN" St="FILED" Dt="2004-01-14"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NV" St="FILED" Dt="2006-07-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NH" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NJ" St="FILED" Dt="2007-04-12"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NM" St="FILED" Dt="2009-11-09"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NY" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="NC" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="ND" St="FILED" Dt="2006-07-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="OH" St="FILED" Dt="2006-07-05"/>
    <States RgltrCd="OK" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="OR" St="FILED" Dt="2011-02-25"/>
    <States RgltrCd="PA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="SD" St="FILED" Dt="2004-04-19"/>
    <States RgltrCd="TN" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-29"/>
    <States RgltrCd="TX" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="UT" St="FILED" Dt="2007-03-30"/>
    <States RgltrCd="VA" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="WI" St="FILED" Dt="2004-03-26"/>
    <States RgltrCd="WA" St="FILED" Dt="2005-07-20"/>
    <States RgltrCd="SC" St="FILED" Dt="2013-03-25"/>
    </NoticeFiled>
    <Filing Dt="2018-03-23" FormVrsn="10/2017"/>
    <FormInfo>
    <Part1A>
    <Item1 Q1F5="0" Q1I="Y" Q1M="N" Q1N="N" Q1O="N">
    <WebAddrs>
    <WebAddr>HTTPS://WWW.LINKEDIN.COM/COMPANY/MINNEAPOLIS-PORTFOLIO-MANAGEMENT-GROUP-LLC/</WebAddr>
    <WebAddr>HTTPS://WWW.MPMGLLC.COM/</WebAddr>
    </WebAddrs>
    </Item1>
    <Item2A Q2A1="Y" Q2A2="N" Q2A4="N" Q2A5="N" Q2A6="N" Q2A7="N" Q2A8="N" Q2A9="N" Q2A10="N" Q2A11="N" Q2A12="N" Q2A13="N"/>
    <Item2B/>
    <Item3A OrgFormNm="Limited Liability Company"/>
    <Item3B Q3B="DECEMBER"/>
    <Item3C StateCD="DE" CntryNm="United States"/>
    <Item5A TtlEmp="9"/>
    <Item5B Q5B1="3" Q5B2="0" Q5B3="3" Q5B4="0" Q5B5="0" Q5B6="5"/>
    <Item5C Q5C1="0" Q5C2="0"/>
    <Item5D Q5DA1="1432" Q5DA3="301265674" Q5DB1="587" Q5DB3="544741016" Q5DC1="0" Q5DC3="0" Q5DD1="0" Q5DD3="0" Q5DE1="0" Q5DE3="0" Q5DF1="0" Q5DF3="0" Q5DG1="12" Q5DG3="4169936" Q5DH1="15" Q5DH3="15232095" Q5DI1="32" Q5DI3="20681901" Q5DJ1="0" Q5DJ3="0" Q5DK1="1" Q5DK2="Fewer than 5 clients" Q5DK3="174127" Q5DM1="27" Q5DM3="33650961" Q5DN1="453" Q5DN3="148740263" Q5DN3Oth="UMA"/>
    <Item5E Q5E1="Y" Q5E2="N" Q5E3="N" Q5E4="N" Q5E5="N" Q5E6="N" Q5E7="N"/>
    <Item5F Q5F1="Y" Q5F2A="883575007" Q5F2B="185080966" Q5F2C="1068655973" Q5F2D="1873" Q5F2E="686" Q5F2F="2559" Q5F3="0"/>
    <Item5G Q5G1="N" Q5G2="Y" Q5G3="N" Q5G4="N" Q5G5="Y" Q5G6="N" Q5G7="N" Q5G8="N" Q5G9="N" Q5G10="N" Q5G11="N" Q5G12="N"/>
    <Item5H/>
    <Item5I Q5I1="Y" Q5I2A="0" Q5I2B="644368000" Q5I2C="0"/>
    <Item5J Q5J1="Y" Q5J2="N"/>
    <Item6A/>
    <Item6B Q6B1="N" Q6B3="N"/>
    <Item7A/>
    <Item7B Q7B="N"/>
    <Item8A Q8A1="N" Q8A2="Y" Q8A3="N"/>
    <Item8B Q8B1="N" Q8B2="N" Q8B3="N"/>
    <Item8C Q8C1="Y" Q8C2="Y" Q8C3="N" Q8C4="N"/>
    <Item8D/>
    <Item8E Q8E="Y"/>
    <Item8F Q8F="N"/>
    <Item8G Q8G1="N"/>
    <Item8H Q8H1="Y" Q8H2="Y"/>
    <Item8I Q8I="N"/>
    <Item9A Q9A1A="Y" Q9A1B="Y" Q9A2A="178800666" Q9A2B="183"/>
    <Item9B Q9B1A="N" Q9B1B="N"/>
    <Item9C Q9C1="N" Q9C2="N" Q9C3="N" Q9C4="N"/>
    <Item9D Q9D1="N" Q9D2="N"/>
    <Item9E/>
    <Item9F Q9F="11"/>
    <Item10A Q10A="N"/>
    <Item11 Q11="N"/>
    <Item11A Q11A1="N" Q11A2="N"/>
    <Item11B Q11B1="N" Q11B2="N"/>
    <Item11C Q11C1="N" Q11C2="N" Q11C3="N" Q11C4="N" Q11C5="N"/>
    <Item11D Q11D1="N" Q11D2="N" Q11D3="N" Q11D4="N" Q11D5="N"/>
    <Item11E Q11E1="N" Q11E2="N" Q11E3="N" Q11E4="N"/>
    <Item11F Q11F="N"/>
    <Item11G Q11G="N"/>
    <Item11H Q11H1A="N" Q11H1B="N" Q11H1C="N" Q11H2="N"/>
    </Part1A>
    </FormInfo>
    </Firm>
    <Firm>
    <Info SECRgnCD="NYRO" FirmCrdNb="161538" SECNb="801-73444" BusNm="SHANNON RIVER FUND MANAGEMENT, LLC" LegalNm="SHANNON RIVER FUND MANAGEMENT, LLC" UmbrRgstn="Y"/>
    <MainAddr Strt1="850 THIRD AVENUE, 13TH FLOOR" City="NEW YORK" State="NY" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="10022" PhNb="212-331-6555" FaxNb="212-331-6982"/>
    <MailingAddr/>
    <Rgstn FirmType="Registered" St="APPROVED" Dt="2012-03-07"/>
    <NoticeFiled/>
    <Filing Dt="2018-06-28" FormVrsn="10/2017"/>
    <FormInfo>
    <Part1A>
    <Item1 Q1F5="1" Q1I="N" Q1M="N" Q1N="N" Q1O="N">
    <WebAddrs/>
    </Item1>
    <Item2A Q2A1="Y" Q2A2="N" Q2A4="N" Q2A5="Y" Q2A6="N" Q2A7="N" Q2A8="N" Q2A9="N" Q2A10="N" Q2A11="N" Q2A12="N" Q2A13="N"/>
    <Item2B/>
    <Item3A OrgFormNm="Limited Liability Company"/>
    <Item3B Q3B="DECEMBER"/>
    <Item3C StateCD="NY" CntryNm="United States"/>
    <Item5A TtlEmp="10"/>
    <Item5B Q5B1="7" Q5B2="0" Q5B3="0" Q5B4="0" Q5B5="0" Q5B6="0"/>
    <Item5C Q5C1="0" Q5C2="56"/>
    <Item5D Q5DD1="1" Q5DD3="12093000" Q5DF1="8" Q5DF3="379344000"/>
    <Item5E Q5E1="Y" Q5E2="N" Q5E3="N" Q5E4="N" Q5E5="N" Q5E6="Y" Q5E7="Y" Q5E7Oth="PERFORMANCE-BASED ALLOCATIONS"/>
    <Item5F Q5F1="Y" Q5F2A="391437000" Q5F2B="0" Q5F2C="391437000" Q5F2D="9" Q5F2E="0" Q5F2F="9"/>
    <Item5G Q5G1="N" Q5G2="N" Q5G3="Y" Q5G4="Y" Q5G5="N" Q5G6="N" Q5G7="N" Q5G8="N" Q5G9="N" Q5G10="N" Q5G11="N" Q5G12="N"/>
    <Item5H/>
    <Item5I Q5I1="N"/>
    <Item5J Q5J1="N" Q5J2="N"/>
    <Item6A/>
    <Item6B Q6B1="N" Q6B3="N"/>
    <Item7A Q7A1="N" Q7A2="Y" Q7A3="N" Q7A4="N" Q7A5="N" Q7A6="N" Q7A7="N" Q7A8="N" Q7A9="N" Q7A10="N" Q7A11="N" Q7A12="N" Q7A13="N" Q7A14="N" Q7A15="N" Q7A16="Y"/>
    <Item7B Q7B="Y"/>
    <Item8A Q8A1="N" Q8A2="Y" Q8A3="N"/>
    <Item8B Q8B1="N" Q8B2="Y" Q8B3="N"/>
    <Item8C Q8C1="Y" Q8C2="Y" Q8C3="Y" Q8C4="Y"/>
    <Item8D Q8D="N"/>
    <Item8E Q8E="N"/>
    <Item8F/>
    <Item8G Q8G1="Y" Q8G2="Y"/>
    <Item8H Q8H1="N" Q8H2="N"/>
    <Item8I Q8I="N"/>
    <Item9A Q9A1A="Y" Q9A1B="Y" Q9A2A="362098000" Q9A2B="7"/>
    <Item9B Q9B1A="Y" Q9B1B="Y" Q9B2A="362098000" Q9B2B="7"/>
    <Item9C Q9C1="N" Q9C2="Y" Q9C3="N" Q9C4="N"/>
    <Item9D Q9D1="N" Q9D2="N"/>
    <Item9E/>
    <Item9F Q9F="5"/>
    <Item10A Q10A="N"/>
    <Item11 Q11="N"/>
    <Item11A Q11A1="N" Q11A2="N"/>
    <Item11B Q11B1="N" Q11B2="N"/>
    <Item11C Q11C1="N" Q11C2="N" Q11C3="N" Q11C4="N" Q11C5="N"/>
    <Item11D Q11D1="N" Q11D2="N" Q11D3="N" Q11D4="N" Q11D5="N"/>
    <Item11E Q11E1="N" Q11E2="N" Q11E3="N" Q11E4="N"/>
    <Item11F Q11F="N"/>
    <Item11G Q11G="N"/>
    <Item11H Q11H1A="N" Q11H1B="N" Q11H1C="N" Q11H2="N"/>
    </Part1A>
    </FormInfo>
    </Firm>
    <Firm>
    <Info SECRgnCD="HQ" FirmCrdNb="167677" SECNb="802-78666" BusNm="AAC BENELUX" LegalNm="AAC BENELUX HOLDING BV"/>
    <MainAddr Strt1="GUSTAV MAHLERPLEIN 106" City="AMSTERDAM" Cntry="Netherlands" PostlCd="1082MA" PhNb="31-0-20-333-1300" FaxNb="31-0-20-333-1318"/>
    <MailingAddr/>
    <Rgstn FirmType="ERA" St="ACTIVE" Dt="2013-10-03"/>
    <NoticeFiled/>
    <Filing Dt="2018-03-05" FormVrsn="10/2017"/>
    <FormInfo>
    <Part1A>
    <Item1 Q1F5="1" Q1I="Y" Q1M="Y" Q1N="N" Q1O="N" Q1P="7245001CTJ6PKMCS4H25">
    <WebAddrs>
    <WebAddr>HTTP://WWW.AACCAPITAL.COM</WebAddr>
    </WebAddrs>
    </Item1>
    <Item2A/>
    <Item2B Q2B1="N" Q2B2="Y" Q2B3="N"/>
    <Item3A OrgFormNm="Other (specify)" OrgFormOthNm="DUTCH LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY (BV)"/>
    <Item3B Q3B="DECEMBER"/>
    <Item3C CntryNm="Netherlands"/>
    <Item5A/>
    <Item5B/>
    <Item5C/>
    <Item5D/>
    <Item5E/>
    <Item5F/>
    <Item5G/>
    <Item5H/>
    <Item5I/>
    <Item5J/>
    <Item6A/>
    <Item6B Q6B1="N" Q6B3="N"/>
    <Item7A Q7A1="N" Q7A2="Y" Q7A3="N" Q7A4="N" Q7A5="N" Q7A6="N" Q7A7="N" Q7A8="N" Q7A9="N" Q7A10="N" Q7A11="N" Q7A12="N" Q7A13="N" Q7A14="N" Q7A15="N" Q7A16="Y"/>
    <Item7B Q7B="Y"/>
    <Item8A/>
    <Item8B/>
    <Item8C/>
    <Item8D/>
    <Item8E/>
    <Item8F/>
    <Item8G/>
    <Item8H/>
    <Item8I/>
    <Item9A/>
    <Item9B/>
    <Item9C/>
    <Item9D/>
    <Item9E/>
    <Item9F/>
    <Item10A Q10A="N"/>
    <Item11 Q11="N"/>
    <Item11A Q11A1="N" Q11A2="N"/>
    <Item11B Q11B1="N" Q11B2="N"/>
    <Item11C Q11C1="N" Q11C2="N" Q11C3="N" Q11C4="N" Q11C5="N"/>
    <Item11D Q11D1="N" Q11D2="N" Q11D3="N" Q11D4="N" Q11D5="N"/>
    <Item11E Q11E1="N" Q11E2="N" Q11E3="N" Q11E4="N"/>
    <Item11F Q11F="N"/>
    <Item11G Q11G="N"/>
    <Item11H Q11H1A="N" Q11H1B="N" Q11H1C="N" Q11H2="N"/>
    </Part1A>
```

Comment: have you tried `XML::xmlToDataFrame()`?

Comment: yes, it publishes one observation and 17k variables, which isn't accurate at all.

Comment: It would help to provide an example of the desired output.